# VBA InStr to check HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel

Trying to check HTML for specific keywords using VBA function InStr but unfortunately it's not returning the correct results. Here's the VBA...

```
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url4
End With

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

promo = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") 
Debug.Print promo
If InStr(promo, "C8") = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "Not Found"
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "Found"
End If
```

Here's the HTML that I'm trying to check for the value in cell C8...

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height=75%; scrollbar-face-color: #D6DFF7; scrollbar-track-color:white;">
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111">

    <tr>
        <td class='Header'>Customer History from  Monday, September 12, 2016 to Monday, October 10, 2016 </td> 
    </tr>

    <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
        <tr>
            <td class="Content" align="center" width="20%"><b>Promotion</b></td>
            <td class="Content" align="center" width="28%"><b>Issue Date</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>                


    <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
    <tr>
        <td class='Content' width="20%"> October Offer  </td>
        <td class='Content' width="28%"> 10/10/2016 10:50:38 AM </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
    <tr>
        <td class='Content' width="20%"> Exclusive Online Promotion! </td>
        <td class='Content' width="28%"> 10/10/2016 10:50:32 AM </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
    <tr>
        <td class='Content' width="20%"> Exclusive October Offer  </td>
        <td class='Content' width="28%"> 10/10/2016 10:50:10 AM </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

No matter what I type into cell C8 I get the same result in C10 which leads me to believe something is wrong with the "promo" variable since the InStr always comes back 0.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: change `"C8"` to `Range("C8").Value`. Even better if you assign parentage to a worksheet.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Beat me by 10 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

`If InStr(promo, "C8") = 0 Then` is looking for the character string "C8" within the string variable `promo`.  To look for the value of the cell C8, you need to say

```
If InStr(promo, ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value) = 0 Then
```

Comment: I apologize, I posted this in haste while I was troubleshooting... my original code had the proper syntax and unfortunately still did not work correctly. For example, I place text in cell C8 that I know is in the html but is still shows as "not found". Any other ideas of what could cause this?

Comment: Corrected code    ` With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url4
    End With
    
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    promo = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("td") 
    If InStr(promo, ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value) = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "Not Found"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "Found"
    End If `